# How to take large input having 50 or more digits using scanf function

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to C language. I am solving the 8th problem of Project Euler and I want to do this on my own. For that I need to take inputs having 50 or more digits. I am unable to do that. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read them to `char*`.